# varchar yy/mm/dd to date azure sql server

Tags: varchar

Im trying to convert a varchar value into a date format.

The varchar value is 99/01/30and the result should be 1999-01-30.

Would somebody help me with this?
I'm trying to do this but :

```
select convert(date, convert(varchar, '99/01/30', 11),23) as date
```

but this gives me an error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
select convert(date, '99/01/30', 2) as date
```

will get you what you want. See also [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) for more information about what the `2` means